# ReactJS-Implementation of ShowPassword Button using this.state in Class component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, I'm currently implementing a loginpage component and I'm having issues receiving the password when the show password button is clicked and the password type becomes text. Clicking the showPassword button will change the type of password to text to make it visible to the user, but clicking the button again won't redirect the type, and once pressing the loginbutton the password value is null in the payload as shown in the images below. Since I'm using this.state instead of userPassword (which works fine as shown in step 4: https://melvingeorge.me/blog/show-or-hide-password-ability-reactjs) for back-end purposes, is there a way to implement this.state to be able to retrieve the password when password is visible.

When the login button is clicked, and the credentials are entered with showing password button enabled, the password of type 'text' doesn't appear in the payload as shown in this image:
[ImageWhenButtonClicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSTZG.png)

When the credentials are inserted and the loginbutton is clicked without showing the password, the password appears in the payload as shown here:
[ImageWhenButtonNotClicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJu1h.png)

```
class LoginPage extends Component
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
        this.togglePassword = this.togglePassword.bind(this);
    }
```

```
  togglePassword(e){
        this.setState({password:e.target.value});
    }
```

```
render(){
return( <main>
...
    <Input placeholder="Type your password here" type={this.state.password ? "password" : "text"}
                value={this.state.password} onChange={this.togglePassword}/>
        <ShowPasswordButton value={this.state.password} onClick={this.togglePassword}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUnlock} size="sm"/>
        </ShowPasswordButton>
...
</main>
);}
```

When trying the following, I receive 'text' in password payload:

```
<ShowPasswordButton type={this.state.password='text'} value={this.state.password} onClick={this.togglePassword}>
```

[type:text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiGUZ.png)

Comment: Can you attach some screenshots describing what you expect it to show and how it's currently showing ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what you expect to happen with `type={this.state.password='text'}` which is not a comparison, but is actually mutating the state.

Comment: Hi All, my apologies for any misunderstanding, I have attached images of what I see in the payload when the showpassword button is clicked and once it's not.

Comment: Hi @Gabriele, I said that because it was the only way I was able to see a value for password in the payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting your states mixed up, as per in the comment above, you're re-assigning the password state on the `ShowPasswordButton` component which is incorrect. I'd advise to use a different state to manage the showing and hiding of the password and leave this.state.username and this.state.password to store the values for the login form.

Here's a working solution below.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      
      this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        showPassword: false,
      };
      
      this.handleUsername = this.handleUsername.bind(this);
      this.handlePassword = this.handlePassword.bind(this);
      this.toggleShowPassword = this.toggleShowPassword.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }
   
   handleUsername(evt) {
      this.setState({
         username: evt.target.value,
      });
   }
   
   handlePassword(evt) {
      this.setState({
         password: evt.target.value,
      });
   }
   
   toggleShowPassword() {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
         showPassword: !prevState.showPassword,
      }));
   }
   
   handleSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      console.log({
          username: this.state.username,
          password: this.state.password,
      });

      alert(`Your username is: ${this.state.username}, your password is ${this.state.password}`);
   }
   
   render() {
      return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsername} placeholder="Username" />
            <input type={!this.state.showPassword ? 'password' : 'text'} value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword} placeholder="Password" />
            <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleShowPassword}>{this.state.showPassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} Password</button>
            <button disabled={this.state.username === '' || this.state.password === ''}>Login</button>
          </form>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```